# How to check current window location against an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Let's say we've got this HTML:

```
<div class="locationhash" data-position="0"></div>
<div class="locationhash" data-position="1000"></div> 
<div class="locationhash" data-position="3000"></div>
<div class="locationhash" data-position="5000"></div>
<div class="locationhash" data-position="8000"></div>
```

where `data-positions` value, in normal conditions would equal to elements height from pages top in `px`.

Im retrieving elements with `.locationhash`, reading its data-position and pushing both values as an object into an array using this code. (works as intended, output in third code sample here)

```
var getSections = function() {
var pageSectionsArr = [];
var pageSections = (document).querySelectorAll('.locationhash');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(pageSections, function(section) {
  var getSectionPos = section.getAttribute('data-position');
  var pageSectionObj = {
    pageSection : section,
    pageSectionPos : getSectionPos
  };
  pageSectionsArr.push(pageSectionObj);
});
console.log(pageSectionsArr)
};

(function recalcSectionPos() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      getSections();
  });
})();
```

**Output looks like this:**

```
[ {div.locationhash, value of its data-position}, 
{div.locationhash, value of its data-position}, ... ]
```

Now i need to check on scroll wether current window.scrollTop() equals any of data-position values so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hFromTop = $(window).scrollTop()
    //cant figure out what should i do next (jquery allowed)
});
```

**Question:** How could i check current window.scrolltop() against multiple values, while user is scrolling so i could make something happen when window.scroll top equals to a value

(I'm using this array because later im gonna read `.locationhash`'s id in order to append it to url using location replace)

Comment: This will help you http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Comment: thank you so much! can you add this as an answer so you can get well deserved +points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed @tushar gupta's advice, also wrapped it in a function checking wether scrolling ended

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
$.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
  var hFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $.each(pageSectionsArr, function(obj) {
      console.log(this + 'is sparta')
      if (~~this.pageSectionPos <= hFromTop && ~~this.pageSectionPos + this.pageSection.offsetHeight > hFromTop) {
        //console.log(this.pageSectionPos)
        var sectionsId = this.pageSection.id
        //console.log(sectionsId)
        window.location.replace('#/'+sectionsId)
      };
    });
}, 250));
});
```